# How to enable http2 protocol in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js

How to enable http2 protocol in nuxt.js app? I have added SSL certificates and enabled modern mode, played with render>http2 settings in nuxt.config.js, but no matter what I try app still serves request with standard http/1.1 protocol. I can't seem to find anything about it in the documentation either.

Here is my nuxt.config.js:

```js
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

export default {
  server: {
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'certs/localhost.key')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'certs/localhost.crt'))
    }
  },

  mode: 'universal',
  modern: true,
  render: {
    http2: {
      push: true, pushAssets: null
    }
  },
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      {charset: 'utf-8'},
      {name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'},
      {hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || ''}
    ],
    link: [
      {rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico'}
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: {color: '#fff'},
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Well, sort of yes and sort of no. Basically you can create Nginx proxy and enable http2 and direct it to nodejs. This way you will have http2 served to your clients. The only problem is when you don't have http2 all the way through you won't be able to do `HTTP2 server push`. As i don't intend to do server push yet it's a viable solution for me.

Comment: Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

You should set your mode to modern:

```
  mode: 'modern'
```

And specify in the render.http2.pushAssets the actual assets that should be pushed (you currently have null in your sample code).

For example:

```
export default {
  // ...
  render: {
    http2: {
      push: true,
      pushAssets: [
        '/css/main.css',
        '/js/main.js'
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: This config will work for Nuxt 2, I suppose. But how to enable HTTP/2 in Nuxt 3?.. There's no render.http2 option in the config...